# Appendix table label

Tags: tables, texstudio, elsarticle, appendix

I am using elsarticle

to compile my file. I have used the following code

```
   \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands


\appendix
\section{Table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{51.}
    \label{51} \tiny
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.05\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \hline 
1&2\\\hline
3&8\\\hline
5&6\\\hline
7&8\\\hline
15&6\\\hline
27&18\\\hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

The output after compiling the title of the table is

**Table A.5: 51.**

I don't want **Table** in the appendix title. Is there a simple way to eliminate it or get the title of the table to be just A.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below:

```
\appendix
\section{Table}
\let\tablename\relax
\begin{table}
...
```